# New-ADUser, Group Policy won't apply

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group-policy

I've recently run a `New-ADUser` PowerShell script in order to create a user in a specific OU in Active Directory, however I've noticed that Group Policy isn't applied whenever I create a new user via PowerShell. If I create a new user in the OU manually, the Group Policy settings are applied.

Have any of you seen this before and if so would you be able to share your knowledge on why this happens when the user is created via PowerShell?

Additional info: The fields which should get populated by Group Policy are the "Logon script" and the "Connect (drive) to: (path)" fields under the "Profile" tab on a Windows 2003 Server Domain Controller.

Here's the script for reference:

```
$serv = "SERVERNAME"
$cred = "admin\admin"
$secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force

$FirstUser  = "NameOne"
$SecondUser = "NameTwo"
$UserOne = Get-ADUser -Identity $FirstUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv
New-ADUser -SAMAccountName $SecondUser -UserPrincipalName "blah@blah.com" -DisplayName $SecondUser -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $secureString -Credential $cred -Server $serv -PassThru
$UserTwo = Get-ADUser -Identity $SecondUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv

foreach ($group in $UserOne.memberof) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $SecondUser -Server $serv
    Write-Output $group
}
```

Comment: This might be a better question for SuperUser, StackOverflow is normally used to help with your actual code. Maybe add your script to your post at least so we can see what is happening? Might get a better response with that

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've updated my post and I'll try posting over at SuperUser too.

Comment: Server 2003 reached end of life more than 2 years ago. Please upgrade. Now.

Comment: I am 99.99% certain that the problem isn't what you think it is. The domain doesn't care what application created the user in an OU. But in any case this is not a stackoverflow question.

Comment: As @AnsgarWiechers said, Server2003 is EOL. Keeping it running is absolutely a serious security risk unless you have a sterile air gap - and even then, ... I'm not sure I believe that sterile air gaps exist.